# Collaboration and Website Customization on Wix Platform

Tags: velo

I recently received an invitation to collaborate on existing Wix website. It’s on Wix Light plan

I have a couple of questions regarding the website customization options available:

Template Change: Would it be possible for me to update the current template of the existing website? I’d like to explore implementing a different free template to give the site a fresh look…

New Website Creation: Alternatively, if changing the template on the existing website poses any limitations, can I design it from scratch or choose another existing template. Once completed, can I link the existing domain to the new website.

Looking forward to the answers from the community.